# Android: How to use 2 layout

Tags: android, view, draw

I'm trying to do an application where there is a background, and with canvas i draw some lines. But there is a problem. Because to make background and other graphicals things i use a .xml file named "activity_main.xml" and after i do 

      `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to activate it. But when i draw the line i must use this:

```
 drawView = new DrawView(this) 
 setContentView(drawView);
```

Where drawView is the class that allow me to draw the line.
So the first setContentView result useless and i don't know how to do some change (for examples the background) if i had to work with drawView!

"You have no way to add a DrawView in your activity_main layout ?"
Sorry, i suppose yes, but i don't know how to do.

Comment: You have no way to add a `DrawView` in your `activity_main` layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your view to your layout like this:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);//your container's id in your activity_main.xml 
drawView = new DrawView(this); 
layout.addView(drawView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the DrawView to your existing layout with `addView()`? 
You'll have to position it correctly of course, probably within a `RelativeLayout`.